# Can Azure Static Web App have querystring parameter surviving login?

Tags: azure-static-web-app

I have an Azure Static Web App where I have the / route authenticated:

```json
{
  "auth": {
    "identityProviders": {
      "google": {
        "registration": {
          "clientIdSettingName": "GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID",
          "clientSecretSettingName": "GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "/",
      "allowedRoles": ["authenticated"]
    }
  ],

  "responseOverrides": {
    "401": {
      "redirect": "/.auth/login/google",
      "statusCode": 302
    }
  }
}
```

I want to call this site like `http://localhost:4280/?container=123`. When I do this I get redirected to `/.auth/login/google` due to the "authenticated" requirement, and the querystring parameter `container=123` is lost. Is there a way to preserve the querystring parameter, so that after authentication I get called with the correct querystring parameter, e.g. `http://localhost:4280/?container=123`?

Comment: Discussion on this topic in the SWA GitHub repo: https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/435, "supported" in redirect rule (hardcoded?!@#$). The workaround suggested is using local storage/cookie. Another option: use URL segments.